# Twilio Api Call timeLimit

Tags: php, twilio

I am working with twilio API voice call between two number, I want to set call duration 30 min, I added parameter timeLimit to 1800 but not working. Always call is disconnected after 15 second.

```
$call = $client->calls
                       ->create("+91xxxxxxxxx", // to
                               "+1xxxxxxxxxxx", // from
                                array(
                                    "url" => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml",
                                    "method" => "GET",
                                    "timeLimit" => 1800,
                                    "statusCallbackMethod" => "POST",
                                    "statusCallback" => "twillostatuscallback.php",
                                    "statusCallbackEvent" => array("initiated","answered","completed")
                                )
                     );
```

Please tell me problem in my code.

Comment: you have syntax errors. look at `timeLimit`

Comment: I edited. Now whats problem?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. When the TwiML ends, the call will end. The TwiML is the voice.xml URL